# Building a tree from a list and isDescendant and isAscendant functions

Tags: algorithm, tree

What would be the sanest way to build a list of trees given a list of elements:

```
[a1, a2, a3, ..., an]
```

and two total functions:

```
isAscendant(ai, aj) : boolean
isDescendant(ai, aj) : boolean
```

Please, note that if `isAscendant(a5, a33) = true`, this does not mean that `a33` is a direct child of `a5`, it could be a grandchild or a great-grandchild etc.

E.g. this list of trees:

```
       a9               a5
      /  \             / | \
[    a4  a7     ,   a6  a2  a8    ]
    /  \
   a1  a3
```

should be build given `[a1,...a9]` and e.g.:

```
isDescendant(a9,a5) = isDescendant(a9,a5) = false = isAscendant(a9,a5) = isAscendant(a9,a5)
isAscendant(a9,a3) = true
isAscendant(a4,a1) = true
isAscendant(a4,a5) = false

... etc.
```

As mentioned, these functions are total, so there’s always an answer for any arguments `ai, aj`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a topological sort, and do it in a layer-by-layer fashion, which means:

1. Find all nodes with no ancestors;
2. Add them all to the next layer;
3. Remove all these nodes;
4. Repeat until no nodes left.